# An infinite family of generalized Pell equations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

Let $m,n,x,y,z$ be positive integers such that $y=m(z-1)+1$ and $yz-1=n(y^2-x^2)$.

If you fix $m$ and $n$ then this is a generalized Pell equation in $x$ and $z$ (i.e., a quadratic Diophantine equation of the sort that can be solved by [this website](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM)).

---

I have 2 specific conjectures, which I have checked computationally for $m,n\leq100$, $z\leq10^7$.

Conjecture 1: If $n\geq2$ then $x,y,z$ are all odd.

Conjecture 2: If $(m,n)\neq(1,1)$ then $z$ is indivisible by $4$.

A proof or counterexample of either of these conjectures would be much appreciated.

---

The table below gives the first four $(x,y,z)$ solutions for fixed $(m,n)$:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}&n=1&n=2&n=3\\\hline m=1&
\begin{array}{c}(1,1,1)\\(1,2,2)\\(1,3,3)\\(1,4,4)\end{array}&
\begin{array}{c}(1,1,1)\\(5,7,7)\\(29,41,41)\\(169,239,239)\end{array}&
\begin{array}{c}(1,1,1)\\(9,11,11)\\(89,109,109)\\(881,1079,1079)\end{array}\\\hline m=2&
\begin{array}{c}(1,1,1)\\(2,3,2)\\(23,33,17)\\(64,91,46)\end{array}&
\begin{array}{c}(1,1,1)\\(167,193,97)\\(32397,37409,18705)\\(6284851,7257121,3628561)\end{array}&
\begin{array}{c}(1,1,1)\\(439,481,241)\\(211597,231793,115897)\\(101989315,111723697,55861849)\end{array}\\\hline m=3&
\begin{array}{c}(1,1,1)\\(3,4,2)\\(69,85,29)\\(287,352,118)\end{array}&
\begin{array}{c}(1,1,1)\\(417,457,153)\\(200993,220177,73393)\\(96878209,106124761,35374921)\end{array}&
\begin{array}{c}(1,1,1)\\(1053,1117,373)\\(1215161,1288873,429625)\\(1402294741,1487358181,495786061)\end{array}
\end{array}$$

In the comments, Will Jagy observed that if $n\geq2$ then the $x$ values satisfy a linear recurrence $x_{n+2}=Cx_{n+1}-x_n$ (and you can do something similar for $y$ and $z$). The table below gives the values of $C$:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}&n=2&n=3&n=4&n=5&n=6&n=7&n=8&n=9&n=10\\\hline m=1&6&10&14&18&22&26&30&34&38\\\hline m=2&194&482&898&1442&2114&2914&3842&4898&6082\\\hline m=3&482&1154&2114&3362&4898&6722&8834&11234&13922\\\hline m=4&898&2114&3842&6082&8834&12098&15874&20162&24962\\\hline m=5&1442&3362&6082&9602&13922&19042&24962&31682&39202\\\hline m=6&2114&4898&8834&13922&20162&27554&36098&45794&\\\hline m=7&2914&6722&12098&19042&27554&37634&49282&&\\\hline m=8&3842&8834&15874&24962&36098&49282&&&\\\hline m=9&4898&11234&20162&31682&45794&&&&\\\hline m=10&6082&13922&24962&39202&&&&&\end{array}$$

Notice the symmetry!

Gottfried Helms observed the formula $C=4(2mn-1)^2-2$ for $m,n\geq2$.

When $m=1$, it looks like $C=4n-2$ for $n\geq2$.

---

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3917294) proves the $m=1$ case of conjecture 2, using methods from Diophantine approximation.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I tinkered around with the equations a bit earlier today, and was able to write it as $ax^2+cz^2=d$, but the process of getting rid of the linear $z$ term seemed to make the constant term rather large.

Comment: Here it is, in all it's glory: $4mn(mn-1)x^2-(2m(mn-1)z-(m-1)(2mn-1))^2=4m(mn-1)-(m-1)^2$. Maybe it can be transformed into a nicer looking expression.

Comment: You can also get an equation in $x$ and $y$: $nm(y^2-x^2)=(y+m)(y-1)$, where the linear $y$ term can be removed by completing the square.

Comment: Oh, that's amazing! I had found some joint linear recurrences (i.e., $(x_{n+1},y_{n+1},z_{n+1})$ in terms of $(x_n,y_n,z_n)$), but there wasn't a discernable pattern as $m$ and $n$ varied. This is much better.

Comment: Right, this is about the automorphisms of the form $u^2 - d v^2.$  There is a predictable matrix $A$ with $A^T H A = H,$  where $H$ is the Hessian matrix of the form. By Cayley-Hamilton, the trace of $A$ becomes the $C$ above. By taking every other line, we switch to $A^2$ which now has trace $C^2 - 2.$  If you displayed some more triples or quadruples of solutions for more pairs (m,n) of modest size, a formula for $C$ will likely become apparent.  Meanwhile, you should be able to borrow Dickson's little 1929 Intro and Buell's Binary Quadratic Forms (about 1990 I think). I'll be back in a bit

Comment: Not quite: it applies to the sequence $5, 1157, 224453,...$ from which we add $1$ then divide by $6$ to get $y.$ so $1158/6 = 193, $ $ 224454/6 = 37409$  The presence of modulus conditions on $y$ says that the recurrence needs a constant term to work properly. Yes, for that one $$y_{j+2} = 194 y_{j+1} - y_j - 32 $$

Comment: Ah, I see. I've added table of values of $C$.

Comment: Just a minor request: why not include the recursion for $n=1$ in the $C$-table? I think $C=2$ would be appropriate?

Comment: The solutions  $(x,y,z)$ form an interlaced sequence. If separated in two subsequences we find a recursion with the same multiplicator. In Pari/GP I did `seq=[1,2,23,64,781,2174,26531,73852]~`  
`seq1a=[1,  23,   781,     26531      ]~`  
`seq1b=[  2,   64,    2174      ,73852]~`  // construct sequences by matrix-multiplication with C=34 `[1,23]*[0,-1;1,34]^m`  and 
`[2,64]*[0,-1;1,34]^m` // with $m=-2$ we can even prepend two entries:
`seq1a=[373,   11,   1,   23,   781,     26531      ]~`  
`seq1b=[    134,   4,   2,   64,    2174      ,73852]~` (Sorry I can't linebreaks)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Oh, that makes a lot of sense, and explains what's going on for $n=1$ and $m\geq2$.

Comment: The **conjecture 1** is easy to prove, **given** that *a)* the recursivity and *b)* the table of $C$ is a correct fact. Because, if $C_{m,n}=2c$ is even, then of course, if only $x_1=1$, the initialization of the $x_3=2cx_2-x_1$ gives an odd value, and this follows immediately for all $x_{k+2}=2cx_{k+1}-x_k$ with $x_k$ odd. Since your table shows the initial values for all $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)$ when $n>1$ and all $C_{m,n}$ are even, it must follow that all $(x,y,z)_k$ are odd for that $n$.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Technically, that would only show that all $x_k$ are odd, but I think that there is a similar recurrence for $y_k$ and $z_k$ which would make them all odd as you say.

Comment: Well, Thomas, the recursion is the same with $y_k,z_k$ only that there is a constant $D_y,D_z$ which is even - however all only empirically found, no analytical formula so far. I've also been imprecise: we moreover need that not only the first entry $(x,y,z)_1$ is odd but as well $(x,y,z)_2$. But unfortunately for nothing of this we have an analytical formula so far. I've tried with W|A, with fixed $(m,n)$ and they give that Binet-like formula; but it is much more hassle than I would like to invest ... Let's see what Will's ansatz gives. Or someone else weighs in...

Comment: I've taken all hypotheses (about $(x,y,z)_1=(1,1,1)$ about structure of $C$ and about the multiplicator-matrix $M$) together and have made a small Pari/GP-program which gives the then complete solutions $(x,y,z)_h$ for arbitrary $h$ for $(m \gt 0,n \gt 1)$ in milliseconds. If something like this is helpful, I can provide it in my answer. For instance it gives for $(m,n)=(13,3)$ $C_{m,n}=23714$ and the following first *4* entries: $$\small \begin{array} {rrr} x&y&z\\ \hline 1&1&1\\ 21713&21997&1693\\ 514902081&521633113&40125625\\ 12210387927121&12370007615941&951539047381 \end{array}$$

Comment: @WillJagy - what happened? Why deleted all your answers? Please leave a small note to let us understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew! Thanks to the help of Will Jagy and Gottfried Helms, I have a complete solution!

Fix positive integers $m$ and $n$.
We will study the equation
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
    mn(y-x)(y+x)=(y-1)(y+m).
\end{equation}
**Classification of Small Solutions**

We begin by classifying the integer solutions to (1) with small $y$ coordinate.

**Case 1:** $y>1$

Assume that $y>1$.
Then the right hand side of (1) is positive, so the left hand side of (1) is also positive.
Then $y^2-x^2$ is positive, so $y^2-x^2\geq2y-1$.
This gives
$$(y-1)(y+m)=mn(y^2-x^2)\geq mn(2y-1).$$
Dividing through by $2y-1$ gives
$$\frac{(y-1)(y+m)}{2y-1}\geq mn.$$
Let $f(y)=(y-1)(y+m)/(2y-1)$.
Note that $f$ is increasing on $(\frac{1}{2},\infty)$.
Let $y_0=2mn-m$.
Then
$$f(y_0)=\frac{2mn(y_0-1)}{2y_0-1}<mn\leq f(y)$$
so $y_0<y$.
Thus, $y\geq2mn-m+1$.

**Case 2:** $-m<y<1$

Assume that $-m<y<1$.
Then the right hand side of (1) is negative, so the left hand side of (1) is also negative.
Then $y^2-x^2$ is negative, so $y^2-x^2\leq2y-1$.
This gives
$$(y-1)(y+m)=mn(y^2-x^2)\leq mn(2y-1).$$
Dividing through by $2y-1$ gives
$$\frac{(y-1)(y+m)}{2y-1}\geq mn.$$
Let $f(y)=(y-1)(y+m)/(2y-1)$.
Note that $f$ is increasing on $(-\infty,\frac{1}{2})$.
Let $y_0=0$.
Then
$$f(y_0)=m\leq mn\leq f(y)$$
so $y_0\leq y$.
Thus, $y=0$.

**Case 3:** $y<-m$

Assume that $y<-m$.
Then the right hand side of (1) is positive, so the left hand side of (1) is also positive.
Then $y^2-x^2$ is positive, so $y^2-x^2\geq-2y-1$.
This gives
$$(y-1)(y+m)=mn(y^2-x^2)\geq mn(-2y-1).$$
Dividing through by $-2y-1$ gives
$$\frac{(y-1)(y+m)}{-2y-1}\geq mn.$$
Let $f(y)=(y-1)(y+m)/(-2y-1)$.
Note that $f$ is decreasing on $(-\infty,-\frac{1}{2})$.
Let $y_0=-2mn-m+2$.
Then
$$f(y_0)=\frac{(y_0-1)(y_0+m)}{-2y_0-1}\leq\frac{(y_0+1)(y_0+m-2)}{-2y_0-1}=\frac{-2mn(y_0+1)}{-2y_0-1}<mn\leq f(y)$$
so $y_0>y$.
Thus, $y\leq-2mn-m+1$.

**Completing the Classification**

**Theorem 1:**
If $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ satisfies (1) then exactly one of the following holds:

- $y\geq2mn-m+2$,
- $(x,y)=(\pm m,m+1)$ and $n=1$,
- $(x,y)=(\pm1,1)$,
- $(x,y)=(\pm1,0)$ and $n=1$,
- $(x,y)=(\pm m,-m)$,
- $(x,y)=(\pm(3m-2),-3m+1)$ and $n=1$,
- $y\leq-2mn-m$.

*Proof:*
We have already shown that either $y\geq2mn-m+1$ or $y=1$ or $y=0$ or $y=-m$ or $y\leq-2mn-m+1$.

- Assume that $y=2mn-m+1$.
  Then (1) becomes
  $$mn(y-x)(y+x)=(2mn-m)(2mn+1).$$
  Dividing through by $m$ and reducing modulo $n$ forces $n=1$.
  Then $y=m+1$ and solving for $x$ gives $x=\pm m$.
- If $y=1$ then solving for $x$ gives $x=\pm1$.
- If $y=0$ then solving for $x$ gives $nx^2=1$.
  This forces $n=1$ and $x=\pm1$.
- If $y=-m$ then solving for $x$ gives $x=\pm m$.
- Assume that $y=-2mn-m+1$.
  Then (1) becomes
  $$mn(y-x)(y+x)=(2mn+m)(2mn-1).$$
  Dividing through by $m$ and reducing modulo $n$ forces $n=1$.
  Then $y=-3m+1$ and solving for $x$ gives $x=\pm(3m-2)$. $\blacksquare$

**Mapping Solutions**

We now define functions $f,g\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ that preserve integer solutions to (1).
Our goal is to show that every integer solution to (1) can be obtained via $f$ and $g$ from one of the five solutions listed in Theorem 1.

Let $R=2mn-1$.
Let $f,g\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be defined by
$$f\left(\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}(2R^2-1)x+2R(R-1)y-2(m-1)R\\(2R^2-1)y+2R(R+1)x-2(m-1)(R+1)\end{bmatrix},$$
$$g\left(\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}(2R^2-1)x-2R(R-1)y+2(m-1)R\\(2R^2-1)y-2R(R+1)x-2(m-1)(R+1)\end{bmatrix}.$$

**Lemma 2:**
The functions $f$ and $g$ preserve solutions to (1).

*Proof:*
The algebraic manipulations are rather involved, so I instead wrote up a proof in Lean 3.

```
import tactic.ring

variables {A : Type*} [comm_ring A]

lemma lem0 {a b c d : A} (h : a = b) : c - a = d - b → c = d :=
by { rw h, exact sub_left_inj.mp }

structure sol (m n : A) :=
(x y : A)
(h : m * n * (y - x) * (y + x) = (y - 1) * (y + m))

def R (m n : A) : A := 2 * m * n - 1

def sol.forward {m n : A} (s : sol m n) : sol m n :=
{ x := (2*(R m n)*(R m n)-1)*s.x+2*(R m n)*((R m n)-1)*s.y-2*(m-1)*(R m n),
  y := (2*(R m n)*(R m n)-1)*s.y+2*(R m n)*((R m n)+1)*s.x-2*(m-1)*((R m n)+1),
  h := by { dsimp only [R], apply lem0 s.h, ring } }

def sol.backward {m n : A} (s : sol m n) : sol m n :=
{ x := (2*(R m n)*(R m n)-1)*s.x-2*(R m n)*((R m n)-1)*s.y+2*(m-1)*(R m n),
  y := (2*(R m n)*(R m n)-1)*s.y-2*(R m n)*((R m n)+1)*s.x-2*(m-1)*((R m n)+1),
  h := by { dsimp only [R], apply lem0 s.h, ring } }
```

You just need to check that I correctly copied (1) (sol.h), $f$ (sol.forward), and $g$ (sol.backward). $\blacksquare$

We now give a few lemmas describing the relationship between $f$ and $g$.

**Lemma 3:**
Let $\overline{(x,y)}=(-x,y)$.
Then $f(\overline{p})=\overline{g(p)}$ for all points $p\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

*Proof:*
This is clear from the definitions of $f$ and $g$. $\blacksquare$

**Lemma 4:**
The functions $f$ and $g$ are inverses to each other.

*Proof:*
We can write $f$ in terms of matrix multiplication as
$$f\left(\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}2R^2-1&2R(R-1)\\2R(R+1)&2R^2-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}-2(m-1)\begin{bmatrix}R\\R+1\end{bmatrix}.$$
Note that the $2\times2$ matrix has determinant $(2R^2-1)^2-4R^2(R^2-1)=1$.
Then the inverse function to $f$ is given by
\begin{align*}
f^{-1}\left(\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\right)&=\begin{bmatrix}2R^2-1&2R(R-1)\\2R(R+1)&2R^2-1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\left(\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}+2(m-1)\begin{bmatrix}R\\R+1\end{bmatrix}\right)\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}2R^2-1&-2R(R-1)\\-2R(R+1)&2R^2-1\end{bmatrix}\left(\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}+2(m-1)\begin{bmatrix}R\\R+1\end{bmatrix}\right)\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}2R^2-1&-2R(R-1)\\-2R(R+1)&2R^2-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}+2(m-1)\begin{bmatrix}2R^2-1&-2R(R-1)\\-2R(R+1)&2R^2-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}R\\R+1\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}2R^2-1&-2R(R-1)\\-2R(R+1)&2R^2-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}+2(m-1)\begin{bmatrix}R\\-(R+1)\end{bmatrix}=g\left(\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\right).
\end{align*}
Thus, $f$ and $g$ are inverses to each other. $\blacksquare$

By Lemma 4, fixed points of $f$ are fixed points of $g$, and vice versa.

**Lemma 5:**
If $(x,y)$ is a fixed point of $f$ and $g$ then $x=0$.

*Proof:*
Suppose that $(x,y)$ is a fixed point of $f$ and $g$.
Then
$$\begin{bmatrix}2R^2-1&2R(R-1)\\2R(R+1)&2R^2-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}-2(m-1)\begin{bmatrix}R\\R+1\end{bmatrix}=f\left(\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}.$$
Rearranging terms and dividing through by 2 gives
\begin{equation}\tag{2}\begin{bmatrix}R^2-1&R(R-1)\\R(R+1)&R^2-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=(m-1)\begin{bmatrix}R\\R+1\end{bmatrix}.\end{equation}
Note that the $2\times2$ matrix has determinant $(R^2-1)^2-R^2(R^2-1)=1-R^2$.
If $R=1$ then $(m,n)=(1,1)$, so (2) becomes
$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\2&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$
This forces $x=0$.
Now suppose that $R>1$.
Then the $2\times2$ matrix in (2) is invertible, so (2) has a unique solution.
In other words, $f$ and $g$ have a unique fixed point $p$.
However, Lemma 3 shows that $\overline{p}$ is also a fixed point of $f$ and $g$.
Then $p=\overline{p}$, so $x=0$.
Alternatively, you can solve (2) explicitly and get $(x,y)=(0,(m-1)/(R-1))$. $\blacksquare$

**Lemma 6:**
The functions $f,g\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ have no fixed points satisfying equation (1).

*Proof:*
Let $(x,y)$ be a fixed point of $f$ and $g$.
By Lemma 5, $x=0$.
However, setting $x=0$ in (1) gives
$$mny^2=(y-1)(y+m).$$
The quadratic $(mn-1)y^2-(m-1)y+m$ has discriminant $(m-1)^2-4m(mn-1)<0$. $\blacksquare$

We can now prove the main theorem.

**Theorem 7:**
Any integer solution to (1) can be mapped via $f$ and $g$ to one of the five solutions listed in Theorem 1.

*Proof:*
Since the quadratic $(mn-1)y^2-(m-1)y+m$ has negative discriminant, the graph of (1) consists of the two curves $x=\pm\sqrt{y^2-((y-1)(y+m)/(mn))}$.
Since $f(-1,1)=(1-2mR,1-2m(R+1))$ has negative $x$-coordinate, $f$ and $g$ do not swap the two curves.
By Lemma 6, $f$ and $g$ do not flip either of the two curves, and each shift each curve either up or down.
Since $f(-1,1)=(1-2mR,1-2m(R+1))$ has negative $y$-coordinate, $f$ shifts the left curve downward.
Then by Lemma 4, $g$ shifts the left curve upward.
Then by Lemma 3, $f$ shifts the right curve upward and $g$ shifts the right curve downward.

It remains to show that $f$ and $g$ can't jump over the gap $-2mn-m+1\leq y\leq2mn-m+1$.
By Lemmas 3 and 4, it suffices to show that if $y_0=2mn-m+1$ and $x_0=\sqrt{y_0^2-((y_0-1)(y_0+m)/(mn))}$ then the $y$-coordinate of $g(x_0,y_0)$ is at least $-2mn-m+1$.
In other words, we need to prove the inequality
$$(2R^2-1)y_0-2R(R+1)x_0-2(m-1)(R+1)\geq-2mn-m+1.$$
Rearranging terms gives the equivalent inequality
$$x_0\leq\frac{(2R^2-1)y_0-2(m-1)(R+1)+2mn+m-1}{2R(R+1)}.$$
Simplifying the right hand side gives the equivalent inequality
$$x_0\leq2mn-m.$$
To prove this, we directly compute
$$y_0^2-x_0^2=\frac{(y_0-1)(y_0+m)}{mn}=\frac{(2mn-m)(2mn+1)}{mn}=4mn-2m+2-\frac{1}{n}\geq4mn-2m+1=y_0^2-(y_0-1)^2.$$
Then $x_0\leq y_0-1$ as desired. $\blacksquare$

**Consequences**

We can combine Theorems 1 and 7 to make conclusions about all integer solutions to (1).

**Theorem 8:**
Let $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ satisfy (1).

- $y\equiv0,1\pmod{m}$.
- If $n\neq1$ and $y\equiv0\pmod{m}$ then $x\equiv y\equiv m\pmod{2}$.
- If $n\neq1$ and $y\equiv1\pmod{m}$ then $x\equiv y\equiv1\pmod{2}$.
- Either way, if $n\neq1$ then $x\equiv y\pmod{2}$.

*Proof:*
Theorem 7 states that any integer solution to (1) can be mapped via $f$ and $g$ to one of the five solutions listed in Theorem 1.
Note that $f$ and $g$ preserve the value of $y\pmod{m}$, $x\pmod{2}$, and $y\pmod{2}$.
Since each of the five solutions listed in Theorem 1 satisfy the theorem statement, all integer solutions to (1) satisfy the theorem statement. $\blacksquare$

**Theorem 9:**
Let $m,n,x,y,z$ be positive integers such that $y=m(z-1)+1$ and $yz-1=n(y^2-x^2)$.

- If $n\geq2$ then $x,y,z$ are all odd.
- If $(m,n)\neq(1,1)$ then $z$ is indivisible by 4.

*Proof:*
Note that
$$mn(y^2-x^2)=m(yz-1)=y(mz)-m=y(y+m-1)-m=(y-1)(y+m)$$
so our previous work applies.
Furthermore, we are in the $y\equiv1\pmod{m}$ case.
By Theorem 8, if $n\geq2$ then $x\equiv y\equiv1\pmod{2}$.
Then the equation $yz-1=n(y^2-x^2)$ forces $z\equiv1\pmod{2}$.

It remains to show that if $m\geq2$ and $n=1$ then $z$ is indivisible by 4.
We know that $(x,y)$ can be mapped via $f$ and $g$ to one of the five solutions listed in Theorem 1.
Since we are in the $y\equiv1\pmod{m}$ case, and since $m\geq2$, we know that $(x,y)$ can be mapped via $f$ and $g$ to $(\pm m,m+1)$ or $(\pm1,1)$ or $(\pm(3m-2),-3m+1)$.
Since $(x,y)$ is in the first quadrant, we know that $(x,y)$ can be obtained from $(1,1)$ or $(m,m+1)$ via repeated application of $f$ (we can discard $(3m-2,-3m+1)$ since $g(m,m+1)=(3m-2,-3m+1)$).
The solution $(1,1)$ has $z=1$.
The solution $(m,m+1)$ has $z=2$.

We now check how applying $f$ changes $z$.
Applying $f$ has the effect
$$y\mapsto(2R^2-1)y+2R(R+1)x-2(m-1)(R+1).$$
In terms of $z$, this is
$$z\mapsto\frac{(2R^2-1)(m(z-1)+1)+2R(R+1)x-2(m-1)(R+1)-1}{m}+1$$
which simplifies to
$$z\mapsto(2R^2-1)z+4nRx-4(m-1)nR.$$
In particular, the value of $z\pmod{4}$ does not change. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, just a comment to supply more data.

I used Pari/GP to detect the polynomial-structure in your C-table, and find the following table containing additional info for the column $n=1$:

```
  m \ n|    1     2     3      4      5      6      7      8  |
    -  +    -     -     -      -      -      -      -      -  +
    1  |    2    34    98    194    322    482    674    898  |   // ????? see note
    2  |   34   194   482    898   1442   2114   2914   3842  |
    3  |   98   482  1154   2114   3362   4898   6722   8834  |
    4  |  194   898  2114   3842   6082   8834  12098  15874  |
    5  |  322  1442  3362   6082   9602  13922  19042  24962  |
    6  |  482  2114  4898   8834  13922  20162  27554  36098  |
    7  |  674  2914  6722  12098  19042  27554  37634  49282  |
    8  |  898  3842  8834  15874  24962  36098  49282  64514  |
    -  +  ...   ...   ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...  +
          ???
```

This table is produced by the small Pari/GP function

`Cpol(m,n='x)= (4*m*n)^2-16*m*n+2   \\ reproduces OP's table for m,n>=2`
or, a bit more symmetric,
`Cpol(m,n='x)= 4*(2*m*n-1)^2 - 2   \\ reproduces OP's table for m,n>=2`
$\qquad \qquad$ <sub>(leaving *n* in the function-call indeterminate gives the $m$'th polynomial in $x$)</sub>

Surprisingly, the first row, (for $m=1$) does not agree with your first row; and the same might occur, if you would supply a first column with $n=1$ of your data (however looking numerically for solutions when $n=1$ agrees with the first column here).
I'm checking further to see what's going on with this.

---

**update1**
I have looked at the solutions for $n=1$ and $m \gt 1$ .

First, with a chosen $m$, I take, from sequential search, the first 6 solutions for $(x,y,z)$. We find, that assuming we have 2 interlaced subsequences, that subsequences $x_a$ and $x_b$ have a simple recursion rule; for $x_a$ and $x_b$ we have
$$x_{a,k+2}=C_{m,1}\cdot x_{a,k+1} - 1 \cdot x_{a,k} \\
  x_{b,k+2}=C_{m,1}\cdot x_{b,k+1} - 1 \cdot x_{b,k} \\\tag {1.x}$$

The empirical data agree with the $C_{m,n}$-values from my proposal.

For the interlaced $y$- and $z$- sequences we have to include a constant value $D_{y,m}$ and $D_{z,m}$ in the recursion formula:
$$ y_{a,k+2}=C_{m,1}\cdot y_{a,k+1} - 1 \cdot y_{a,k} + D_{y,m}\\
  y_{b,k+2}=C_{m,1}\cdot y_{b,k+1} - 1 \cdot y_{b,k} + D_{y,m}\\ \tag {1.y}$$
and
$$ z_{a,k+2}=C_{m,1}\cdot z_{a,k+1} - 1 \cdot z_{a,k} + D_{z,m}\\
  z_{b,k+2}=C_{m,1}\cdot z_{b,k+1} - 1 \cdot z_{b,k} + D_{z,m}\\ \tag {1.z}$$

The complete recursion can be done in a matrix-formula, where the recursion-depth can be formalized by an initial matrix $I$  and the multiplicatormatrix $M$ such that
$$ S_{h+1} = I \cdot M^h $$
gives the $h$'th iteration.

Solutions:

- Let $m=2$.
  The first few empirically found solutions for $(x,y,z)$ are
  empirically the following sequences, obviously by 2 recursive intertwined  subsequences:

  ```
  x=  1  2  23  64   781  2174  26531   73852
  y=  1  3  33  91  1105  3075  37521  104443
  z=  1  2  17  46   553  1538  18761   52222
  ```

The matrix $M$ is
$$ M = \small{ \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&1 \\ 0&0&-1\\0&1&C_{m,1}\end{bmatrix} 
= \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&1 \\ 0&0&-1\\0&1&34\end{bmatrix} }$$

The initmatrix $I$ is composed of the first two empirical values $[x_a,y_a,z_a]$ and $[x_b,y_b,z_b]$, and additionally prepended by the -at the moment- unknown constants $D$ taken as zero:
$$ I_{\text{init}}=\small  \begin{bmatrix} 
0&x_{a,1}&x_{a,2} \\ D_y&y_{a,1}&y_{a,2}\\D_z&z_{a,1}&z_{a,2} \\ 
\hline
0&x_{b,1}&x_{b,2} \\ D_y&y_{b,1}&y_{b,2}\\D_z&z_{b,1}&z_{b,2}
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
0&1&23\\0&1&33\\0&1&17 \\ \hline
0&2&64\\ 0&3&91\\0&2&46
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
If we compute $S_2 = I \cdot M$ we get a wrong result for $y_{a,3},z_{a,3},y_{b,3},z_{a,3}$ - but this differences are then simply the new constant values for $D$ and this gives then
$$ \small I= \begin{bmatrix}
0&1&23\\-16&1&33\\-24&1&17 \\ \hline
0&2&64\\ -16&3&91\\-24&2&46
 \end{bmatrix}$$

With this we can compute the set of solutions using $S_{h+1}=I \cdot M^h$ for $h=0..7$ (or arbitrarily more); I show this having the two subsets as submatrices:
$$\small \begin{bmatrix} 
 o: & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & \cdots \\ \hline 
 x_a: & 1 & 23 & 781 & 26531 & 901273 & 30616751 & 1040068261 & 35331704123 & \cdots \\ 
 y_a: & 1 & 33 & 1105 & 37521 & 1274593 & 43298625 & 1470878641 & 49966575153 & \cdots \\ 
 z_a: & 1 & 17 & 553 & 18761 & 637297 & 21649313 & 735439321 & 24983287577 & \cdots \\ 
 x_b: & 2 & 64 & 2174 & 73852 & 2508794 & 85225144 & 2895146102 & 98349742324 & \cdots \\ 
 y_b: & 3 & 91 & 3075 & 104443 & 3547971 & 120526555 & 4094354883 & 139087539451 & \cdots \\ 
 z_b: & 2 & 46 & 1538 & 52222 & 1773986 & 60263278 & 2047177442 & 69543769726 & \cdots
 \end{bmatrix}$$

Note that we could even insert negative values for $h$ to continue the matrix of solutions to the left side.

---

- Let $m=3$.
  The first few empirically found solutions for $(x,y,z)$ are
  empirically the following sequences, obviously again by 2 recursive intertwined  subsequences:

  ```
  x=    1  3  69  287  6761  28123
  y=    1  4  85  352  8281  34444
  z=    1  2  29  118  2761  11482
  ```

The matrix $M$ is
$$ M = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&1 \\ 0&0&-1\\0&1&98\end{bmatrix} $$

The initmatrix $I$ is made as before and this gives then
$$  I =  \small \begin{bmatrix} 
 0 & 1 & 69 \\ 
 -48 & 1 & 85 \\ 
 -80 & 1 & 29 \\ \hline 
 0 & 3 & 287 \\ 
 -48 & 4 & 352 \\ 
 -80 & 2 & 118
 \end{bmatrix}$$

With this we can compute the set of solutions using $S_{h+1}=I \cdot M^h$ for $h=0..7$ (or arbitrarily more); again I show this having the two subsets as submatrices:
$$\small \begin{bmatrix} 
 o: & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & \cdots \\ \hline 
 x_a: & 1 & 69 & 6761 & 662509 & 64919121 & 6361411349 & 623353393081 & 61082271110589 \\ 
 y_a: & 1 & 85 & 8281 & 811405 & 79509361 & 7791105925 & 763448871241 & 74810198275645 \\ 
 z_a: & 1 & 29 & 2761 & 270469 & 26503121 & 2597035309 & 254482957081 & 24936732758549 \\ \hline 
 x_b: & 3 & 287 & 28123 & 2755767 & 270037043 & 26460874447 & 2592895658763 & 254077313684327 \\ 
 y_b: & 4 & 352 & 34444 & 3375112 & 330726484 & 32407820272 & 3175635660124 & 311179886871832 \\ 
  z_b: &2 & 118 & 11482 & 1125038 & 110242162 & 10802606758 & 1058545220042 & 103726628957278
 \end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: @Will - yeah, this might be a point. What I got with $n=1$ is $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1),(2,3,2)(23,33,17)(64,91,46)...$ whose two subsets of each second parenthese give two sequences with expected $C$ for recursion. When I had this I didn't notice the distinction into *even* and *odd* solutions.

Comment: Gottfried, $m=1$ is strange. If you just ask, "what value of $C$ makes the recurrence hold", then you get my values $C=4n-2$ for $n\geq2$, which doesn't match the formula for $m,n\geq2$. I'm not sure why $m=1$ would be special in this way.

Comment: @ThomasBrowning - hmm, I seem to be running out of ideas at the moment. It's late evening anyway; perhaps I can come back to this tomorrow with some fresh energy. The only, possibly noteworthy, observation I had made so far is that your solutions for $m=1$ contain my solutions here (purely based on the extrapolation of the polynomial rule for all $(n,m)$), plus plus plus many more. So I'll have to look whether I can modify the polynomial function for that case $m=1$ with that multiple more subsets of solutions (likely having still that recursive structure) with some meaningful rationale ...

Comment: @Will, for whatever reason this came to my mind: "Kids are different today, I hear every mother say, mother needs something today to calm her down..."  ;-)

Comment: @Will - my most used resource is the Göttingen Digitalizing Center (at University Göttingen). They have real good Journals; the fact that they look a bit "prehistoric" is not so a problem for me, because that's the level where I can mostly follow. But to be not unfair: many modern english articles, online, well explanative I have (and appreciate much) in my "collection". My own "articles" are not much more than explorative, compared to that...

Comment: @WillJagy I apologize if my comment came off as dismissive or rude. I have been reading through your answers carefully and was just hoping that you might include a sentence or two at the end explaining how the classification that you obtained implies the parity conjecture. I also had one or two more specific questions, like how you got the congruence $w\equiv R-m\pmod{m(R-1)}$. You have put a lot of time into your answers, and I have learned a lot from them, and I want to reward you for them.